# An alternative term for ' increasing competition'

Tags: phrase-requests

The context is the tech market where there are frequently  new products and companies have to face an ever increasing competition. I am looking for a similar  expression to 'increasing competition' to express the concept described.

Comment: Some context would be nice. Do you mean you want to raise the stakes (make the competition tougher), or level the playing field (allow more people to enter the game)? Do you mean competition as in businesses operating in the same industry, or do you mean competition as in a game between two opponents? Do you want to increase something, or are you observing an increase?

Comment: could it be: "enhance competition level"

Comment: I'm just looking for  an equivalent definition, with different wording.

Comment: @Jack: Please be more clear of _what_ you are looking for a definition. "Increasing competition" can mean very very many things: "we notice there is increasing competition in the industry", "because of new regulations, we will work on increasing competition", "there was increasing competition between the two tennis players". Please give us some **context**, an example sentence where you are using "increasing competition" so that we know whether you want to level the playing field or you want to raise the stakes, or you want something else.

Comment: Ok the context is: Company X is considering  to take new measures to contrast the increasing competition within its sector. (create new products or improve distribution). Hope it is clear.

Comment: Synonyms for both *increasing* and *competition* can be looked up in a thesaurus. But it's not clear what you think is wrong with "increasing competition" in the first place. Looking for alternatives for these particular two words, and not any of the other words in that sentence strikes me as completely arbitrary. In fact one might humbly submit that "increasing competition" is the one part of that sentence that needs the least rewording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible alternative, I think, would be this:

> Company X is considering taking new measures to contrast the
>   new competitors within its sector.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest **intensifying fight for market share** as an alternative to *increasing competition*

Answer (score -2):

The word I would suggest is **cut-throat competition**

Comment: That's a collocation (or perhaps an idiom).

Answer (score -2):

Keep it simple:

"Company X is considering new measures in order to bolster its position within a growing sector."